# getting an attribution error that AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops' has no attribute '_TensorLike' in tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation

I'm trying to make encoder decoder like model where I'm getting the following error at model.fit

```
 AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops' has no attribute '_TensorLike'

model.fit(train_dataloader,
      validation_data = test_dataloader,
      steps_per_epoch=len(train_dataset)//8,
      epochs=10)
```

I'm using keras 2.3.1 and segmentaion-model

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in latest keras version 2.6.0

Workaround for older Keras version

Change `is_tensor` in file `keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py`, as of keras with `tensorflow 2.3.0`

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_util
def is_tensor(x):                                                                                                                                                      
    return tensor_util.is_tensor(x)
    #return isinstance(x, tf_ops._TensorLike) or tf_ops.is_dense_tensor_like(x)
```